# Spring boot - how to use a PEM certificate with a password-protected private key?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl

**Is it possible to accomplish this via application.yml configuration alone? I am running Spring Boot v3.1.4.**

I've created an SSL certificate using win-acme and I'm trying to deploy it in my spring boot application. I've got it working with a nonpassword-protected private key, but I want to encrypt it with a password for enhanced security. My new certificate and private key are configured, and I've got my application.yml set up, however it's telling me the RSA format is unrecognized.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error loading private key file: Unrecognized private key format
        at org.springframework.boot.ssl.pem.PemPrivateKeyParser.parse(PemPrivateKeyParser.java:200)
        at org.springframework.boot.ssl.pem.PemSslStoreBundle.createKeyStore(PemSslStoreBundle.java:92)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unrecognized private key format
        at org.springframework.boot.ssl.pem.PemPrivateKeyParser.parse(PemPrivateKeyParser.java:197)
        ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Here is my application.yml:

```
server:
  port: ${PORT}
  ssl:
    certificate: C:\cert\crt.pem
    certificate-private-key: C:\cert\key.pem
    key-store-password: 1234567890
```

Here are the first few lines of my private key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC
```

Comment: **Your file is indeed wrong.** The PEM format for `RSA PRIVATE KEY` de-facto standardized by OpenSSL has the word `ENCRYPTED` at the end of line 2 (after the comma) and NOT the beginning of line 3. Also line 3 needs to have the cipher (AES-256-CBC) followed by a comma and the salt-also-IV value in hex. You don't say anything about how this was created so I can't advise, although it doesn't look like a programming issue.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 sorry, I pasted it in wrong. the ENCRYPTED should indeed occur on line 2. I created it with win-acme, which is an implementation of acme on windows. I am lacking the salt-also-IV, so I will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Password-protected private keys are supported with the [SSL Bundles](https://spring.io/blog/2023/06/07/securing-spring-boot-applications-with-ssl) feature that was made available in Spring Boot 3.1. Configure a bundle, including the `private-key-password` property, then apply the bundle to your web server.

```
spring:
  ssl:
    bundle:
      pem:
        server:
          keystore:
            certificate: C:\cert\crt.pem
            private-key: C:\cert\key.pem
            private-key-password: 1234567890
          
server:
  port: ${PORT}
  ssl:
    bundle: "server"
```